# In what year were the Jews in Beitar killed? In what year were they allowed to be buried?

Tags: history, funeral-burial-levaya, 15th-of-av

Wondering how many years were they not allowed to be buried for. What year were they finally allowed?

Answer (score 1):

According to chabad.org,

- [Beitar fell](https://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day_cdo/aid/294197/jewish/Fall-of-Betar.htm) on the 9th of Av of the year 3893 (133 CE)
- [the dead were buried](https://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day_cdo/aid/291472/jewish/Betar-Dead-Buried.htm) **15 years later** on the 15th Av of the year 3908 (148 CE).

See [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144572/jewish/The-Fall-of-Betar.htm) for further background and some of the Talmudic sources [here](https://www.sefaria.org/topics/beitar?tab=sources).